# Check on save if Site already exist

Tags: 7, path-aliases, nodes

When a new page is created and the path already exists, drupal automatically converts it to path_n .
Which behavior I want here instead:
A message that the path already exists, with two buttons one to go back and one to create path_n.
How could I add this behavior?
(think hook_node_create is a good start, or is there even a module?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unique Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/unique_field) is the closest module you'll find. Assuming you use a field like title on your url path this would work, but without the continue anyways option. Although looking at the module code might help you out in building your own custom module.

Comment: Not exacltly what I searched for, but it's a good start.